# Fast way to get number of files matching a pattern

Tags: unix, filesystems, ls

I have a directory that has 8K files at the moment.  Over the next month or so that number will grow to 100K plus.  I need to be able to count the files in the directory matching a particular pattern.  The pattern match adds an enormous amount of time:

```
[XXXXXX@login-0-0 scripts]$ time ls | grep . -c
8373

real    0m0.115s
user    0m0.109s
sys 0m0.009s
[XXXXXX@login-0-0 scripts]$ time ls *.o* | grep . -c
6262

real    0m1.997s
user    0m0.121s
sys 0m0.270s
```

As the number of files continues to increase the time to count by pattern will become too great.  Can I get around this?

As a side note, the filesystem is Lustre, and I can deal with a non-portable solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps what's slowing you down is that your glob is actually expanded by bash and the parameters are passed to ls, so it's a bit of extra work. This works for me:

```
user@host:~/junk$ time find . | wc -l
188318

real    0m0.202s
user    0m0.076s
sys 0m0.136s

user@host:~/junk$ time find . -name '*.o' | wc -l
374

real    0m0.243s
user    0m0.160s
sys 0m0.080s
```

Not much difference in speed.  Note that this is recursive, but you can set the maxdepth if you don't want that.

Maybe it's time for me to clean up some junk...

Comment: If a file has a newline in its name, it may be counted as two or more files. I would do this: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.o' -printf "\n" | wc -l`. (In this case, `-name '*.o'` prevents `.` from being counted, but in other cases you may also need `-mindepth 1` to exclude `.`.)